# How To Rewrite WordPress Pages URL Only?

Tags: plugins, url-rewriting, urls, htaccess

I have my WordPress pages URL as `www.example.com/WP/sample-page` and I want to make it like `www.example.com/WP/p/sample-page.html` For this purpose I used a Plugin name ["**Pages with extension**"](http://wordpress.org/plugins/pages-with-extension/) and it worked but it only add .html in the end of my pages URL. I also want to add `/p/` before my pages URL so that it will become as I mentioned above. I dont want to use any extention for this purpose, Can `.htaccess` file do it? If yes then how?

Comment: What about adding them all as children of a page with slug `p`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I shared above that I got `.html` in page by a Plugin. The rest of the problem is to add `/p/` before page name that I got also as **TheDeadMedic** mentioned above. I just created a page with URL `www.example.com/WP/p.html` and then created another desired page with URL `www.example.com/WP/sample-page.html` but add the second page as the child of first `www.example.com/WP/p.html` page. Then I open my desired page then I got the URL as I want `www.example.com/WP/p/sample-page.html` and I got my problem solved.

Get All Steps In Pic By **wikiHow** at: [How to Add a Subpage in Wordpress](http://www.wikihow.com/Add-a-Subpage-in-Wordpress)